# Heroku + DockHero

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm facing some problems to deploy an application to DockHero. As you can see, I'm trying to run this command as heroku says in its documentation:

```
ubuntu@ip-***-**-**-**:~/syncfusion$ heroku dh:compose up -d -a APP_NAME
```

But this happens:

```
Unknow flag: --file
See 'docker --help'.
```

This is my dockhero-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  word-processor-server:
    image: syncfusion/word-processor-server:latest
    environment:
      SYNCFUSION_LICENSE_KEY: MY_LICENSE
    ports:
    - "6002:80"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) installed locally?

It [looks like](https://github.com/dockhero/dockhero-cli/blob/2d741bd24bd991c073d4aeabe9bf16f67264d793/commands/compose.js#L17-L21) `heroku dh:compose up -d -a foo` just runs

```
docker compose --file dockhero-compose.yml -p dockhero up -d -a foo
```

But if Docker Compose is not correctly installed you should get an error like the one you are seeing.

---

On some operating systems it looks like Docker Compose doesn't get properly added as a Docker subcommand. I.e., `docker-compose` works but `docker compose` does not.

Since `heroku dh:compose` runs `docker compose`, it will fail on such systems.

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/thaJeztah/b7950186212a49e91a806689e66b317d) shows one way to register Docker Compose as a Docker subcommand:

1. Create a `~/.docker/cli-plugins` directory:

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
   ```
2. Create a file `~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose` containing the script shown below
3. Make that file executable:

   ```
    chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
   ```

That should register Docker Compose as a Docker plugin so you can run `docker compose`, which should in turn make `heroku dh:compose` work.

Script from the Gist:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker_cli_plugin_metadata() {
    if [ -z "$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION" ]; then
        export DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION="$(docker-compose --version | cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d "," -f 1)"
    fi

    local vendor="Docker"
    local url="https://www.docker.com"
    local description="Define and run multi-container applications"
    cat <<-EOF
    {"SchemaVersion":"0.1.0","Vendor":"${vendor}","Version":"${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}","ShortDescription":"${description}","URL":"${url}"}
EOF
}

case "$1" in
    docker-cli-plugin-metadata)
        docker_cli_plugin_metadata
        ;;
    *)
        exec "docker-$@"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: It worked!! Dude you are awesome!! Thank you so much for that!